# Passing a variable in Selenium Xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to pass a variable in Xpath but it is not capturing it .

The Country is captured in query using speech recognisation
My Code ::

**
while True:
query = command().lower()
    Country = ['Germany', 'Netherlands']
    for Country in query:

```
     if Country in Country:

        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='ot-lookup__input-container'])").click()

        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize 
                                          space()=\'{}\']"))).format(query).click()
     else:
        speak("Not a valid Country")
     break**
```

If I am giving space()='Germany', then it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.format()** is not on correct place. **.format()** should be apply on **xpath** string instead outside **)))**.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='{}']".format('Other')))).click()
```

Comment: Hi corrected the statement , but getting the below error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/c296442/PycharmProjects/Robi/venv/Scripts/One Trust.py", line 79, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalizespace() =\'{}\']".format(query)))).click()
  File "C:\Users\c296442\PycharmProjects\Robi\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Hello Kunal now it is related to locator. Selenium not able to find locator in DOM. Try without slashes near {}. I have updated my answer too. It is used for new line generally

Comment: Sorry. It can be failed also if element is not clickable. As we are waiting for element to receive click

Comment: Hi , Failing now also , but if I am using the Harcoded Text .. I am using below code ..Can you check why it is failing driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//button[normalize-space()="+ query + "]").click()

Comment: yes it work perfectly with Harcoded value wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Other']"))).click()

Comment: Yes. so we are doing wrong we are using normalizespace. Please check updated answer

Comment: @Kunal Please check updated answer and let me know.